# Track file read / access

Tags: powershell

is it possible to monitor with PowerShell any (attempted) file access (read, write, ...) for a file?

The reason for this question: On one platform I get an error, that a method could not be found. On any other, the program is running .

I found much about auditing in Windows but that does not work in my usecase.

Kind regards
Niklas

Comment: Please show us the code you already seem to have and include the error message. Don't add this info as a comment, but EDIT your question and format the code and error.

Comment: to mention a keyword: filesystemwatcher

Comment: If you can trigger the error you can always use something like procmon and filter on the path of your file

Comment: For help with your code: *show* your code. With that said, this sounds like you actually want a [security audit policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/basic-audit-object-access).